# Cassandra Insert with clustering key null is working but not while coping from csv using cql

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Cassandra Insert with clustering key null is working but not while coping from csv using cql

For ex :

```
CREATE TABLE tracks_by_album (
  album_title TEXT,
  album_year INT,
  performer TEXT STATIC,
  album_genre TEXT STATIC,
  track_number INT,
  track_title TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY ((album_title, album_year), track_number)
);

Insert into tracks_by_album(album_title,album_year,performer) values ('test',2011,'myself') working
```

But copy command with `track_number` null is not working. Getting the error:

```
Failed to import 2 rows: InvalidRequest - Error from server: 
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid null value in condition for column 
track_number",  will retry later, attempt 1 of 5
```

Comment: Why do you need to inset null on clustering column ?

Comment: actually I have multiple dataset to import. In first dataset I want to keep clustering key null.

Comment: which cassandra and cqlsh version are you using ?

Comment: I am using Cassandra 3.10

Answer (score 1):

Static field are static, partition key wise, That's why cassandra allow you to insert static value even if you have not specified clustering key. For your case `(album_title, album_year)` is the partition key and `performer` is the static field. That's why cassandra allow you to insert `performer` even though you have not specified clustering key `track_number`.

But cqlsh not allowing you to import data without all the primary key, you can call that a bug of cqlsh.

By the way you can import data with cqlsh if you provide a dummy value of `track_number` i.e. `0`